# Quarter over Quarter in r

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, aggregate-functions, summary

I have been trying to calculate the quarter over quarter change in shares with no luck. I have a data.table with approx 15millions rows. 
What I need to calculate is the change in absolute values quarter by quarter according to the Holder and the stock they own.
My data table looks like this:

```
stock      Holder                           Quarter  Shares
1: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2015 Q3  5800            
2: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2015 Q4  9000            
3: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2016 Q1  7000             
4: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2016 Q2  7560             
5: GOOGLE  Advest, Inc.                     2015 Q3  12000
6: GOOGLE  Advest, Inc.                     2015 Q3  13450
```

I'm trying to use data.table functions, using

```
df[, qoq := c(NA, diff(Shares)), by = "Holder,stock,Quarter"]
```

However, I get only NA.

I was expecting something like this:

```
stock      Holder                           Quarter  Shares qoq
1: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2015 Q3  5800   NA           
2: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2015 Q4  9000   4000         
3: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2016 Q1  7000   -2000          
4: GOOGLE  Advance Capital Management, Inc. 2016 Q2  7560    560         
5: GOOGLE  Advest, Inc.                     2015 Q3  12000   NA
6: GOOGLE  Advest, Inc.                     2015 Q3  13450  1450
```

After that, I need to calculate the variance of this result, again, by Holder and stock. Is there any general function to calculate statistics by grouping several columns? I tried aggregate but is taking yearsssss...

```
aggregate(REPORTED_HOLDING~Quarter+FILER_NAME+STOCK_NAME, FUN=sum, data=df)
```

Comment: If you read the data.table vignettes, you'll see a simple fast syntax for doing aggregations, like `DT[, sum(x), by=.(y,z)]` where x, y and z are columns.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks! I read the vignettes. Now I know more about data tables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, assuming `df` is you data.**frame**:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(stock, Holder) %>% 
    mutate(qoq = Shares - lag(Shares)) %>% 
    summarise(qvar = var(qoq, na.rm = T))
```